# how to understand the relationships in the model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Such as how to get data from another of the same model?
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ usually write as to establish a relationship between the models, but it is not clear in this case to get the data
can consult books or online resources with examples?

Example:

```
class Foto <ActiveRecord :: Base
   belongs_to: action
End

class Action <ActiveRecord :: Base
   has_many: foto
end

ActiveRecord :: Schema.define (version: 20151207105829) do
   create_table "actions", force:: cascade do | t |
     t.text "name"
   end
   create_table "fotos", force:: cascade do | t |
     t.text "fname"
     t.integer "action_id"
     t.text "image"
   end
end
```

how to get the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM fotos
  INNER JOIN actions ON fotos.action_id = actions.id
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: `Foto.joins(:action)` for inner join

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard [`belongs_to/has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) relationship -- you're looking to *associate* two models through a database reference.

--

You've already done the hard work - you have the relevant `foreign_key` in your database (`action_id`), which means you'll be able to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :actions do
   resources :fotos, only: [:new, :create]
end

#app/controllers/fotos_controller.rb
class FotosController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @action = Action.find params[:action_id]
      @foto = @action.fotos.new
   end

   def create
      @action = Action.find params[:action_id]
      @foto = @action.fotos.new foto_params
   end

   private

   def foto_params
      params.require(:foto).permit(:fname, :image)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The below ActiveRecord statement should give you the fotos for a particular action

```
Action.find(name: "pass the name here").fotos
```

or if you wan to traverse in the opposite relation

```
Foto.find(fname: "pass the fname here").action
```

**Note**
Your relationship is important, because you will need to pluralize the name of classes to fetch them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Rich Peck has completely right answer. But he should add that you can get all off the photos by using `@action.fotos` after you will create some of them.

I.e. `@action.fotos` will store all of your fotos which are belonging to some @action and will correspond to

```
SELECT * FROM fotos
INNER JOIN actions ON fotos.action_id = actions.id
```